# Filtering all cases of users from data if user has logged in before prior date with Dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Using dplyr, trying to filter any user who has logged in before 1/5 from the whole data frame.

```
User  Date 
A     1/1   
A     1/2   
A     1/5
A     1/7   
B     1/2   
C     1/6 
D     1/4
D     1/7
```

Expected result:

```
User  Date
C     1/6
```

Since A and D has logged in prior to 1/5, I want them to be removed from the data frame entirely.

I am able to identify the users who have logged in prior to 1/5. But I don't know how to remove them from my DF without having to manually filter each user by filter(User != ""). This would be problematic when there is a large list of users.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the data is ordered by "Date" within each group ("User"),  specify the grouping variable as "User" (`group_by(.)`), convert the "Date" to `Date` class by creating a new column "Date1", check whether the first value of "Date1" is greater than "1/5" and use `filter` to subset the rows.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(User) %>% 
   mutate(Date1=as.Date(paste0(Date,'/2015'), format='%m/%d/%Y')) %>% 
   filter(Date1[1] >=as.Date('2015-01-05')) %>%
   select(-Date1)
#    User Date
#1    C  1/6
```